Django Password form not loading
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/5/password/
Using the URLconf defined in My_Blog_Project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
account/
blog/
\[name='index'\]
The current path, 5/password/, didn’t match any of these.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

views.py
@login_required
def pass_change(request):
    current_user = request.user
    change = False
    form = PasswordChangeForm(current_user)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PasswordChangeForm(current_user, data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    change = True
    return render(
        request,
        "App_Login/pass_change.html",
        context={"form": form, "change": change},
    )

pass_change.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% crispy form %}

{% block title_block %}
    Change Password
{% endblock %}

{% block body_block %}
    {% if change %}
        Password changed successfully.
    {% endif %}
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    Change Password
{% endblock %}

url pattern for my App_login app
path('password/',views.pass_change, name='pass_change')

main urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("account/", include("App_Login.urls")),
    path("blog/", include("App_Blog.urls")),
    path("", views.Index, name="index"),
]

How can i solve this issue?

If youre trying to trying to send data with a form to the python backend it should be a POST. I see the method is looking for it but the browser sent a GET request somehow, post the code if the problem isnt fixed.

See your URL, /5/password/ does not match your path.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
